# Add custom comment to wordpress script in source code

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to add a comment inside my script so that whenever I view page source I can see that comment. The code I have is:

```
public function front_scripts() {

    // Make sure that the GA ttracking code is being included
    if ( 'on' === $GLOBALS['WP_MyPluginOne']->settings->get_option( 'install_ga_code', 'wp-MyPluginOne-profile', 'off' ) ) {

        global $current_user;

        $roles = $current_user->roles;

        if ( ! isset( $roles[0] ) or ! in_array( $roles[0], $GLOBALS['WP_MyPluginOne']->settings->get_option( 'exclude_users_tracking', 'wp-MyPluginOne-profile', array() ) ) ) {

            wp_enqueue_script( 'MyPluginOne-events-tracking', plugins_url( 'assets/js/MyPluginOne-events-tracking.min.js', __DIR__ ), array( 'jquery' ) );
            add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', array( $this, 'add_script_comment_to_tracking_min' ), 10, 3 );
            wp_localize_script(
                'MyPluginOne-events-tracking',
                'MyPluginOne_events_tracking',
                array(
                    'ajaxurl'            => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
                    'tracking_mode'      => MyPluginOne_TRACKING_MODE,
                    'ga_mode'            => method_exists( 'WPMyPluginOne_Utils', 'get_ga_mode' ) ? WPMyPluginOne_Utils::get_ga_mode() : 'ga3',
                    'tracking_code'      => WP_MyPluginOne_FUNCTIONS::get_UA_code(),
                    'is_track_user'      => MyPluginOne_is_track_user(),
                    'root_domain'        => $this->get_root_domain(),
                    'affiliate_link'     => $GLOBALS['WP_MyPluginOne']->settings->get_option( 'affiliate_link_path', 'wp-MyPluginOne-events-tracking', '' ),
                    'download_extension' => $GLOBALS['WP_MyPluginOne']->settings->get_option( 'file_extension', 'wp-MyPluginOne-events-tracking', 'zip|mp3*|mpe*g|pdf|docx*|pptx*|xlsx*|rar*' ),
                    'anchor_tracking'    => $GLOBALS['WP_MyPluginOne']->settings->get_option( 'anchor_tracking', 'wp-MyPluginOne-events-tracking' ),
                )
            );
        }
    }
}
```

And the way I want the comment to be is:

```
<script id="MyPluginOne-events-tracking-js-extra">
/* the comment to be shown. */
var MyPluginOne_events_tracking = {"ajaxurl":"http:\/\/MyPluginOne-github.local\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php","tracking_mode":"gtag","ga_mode":"ga4","tracking_code":"G-PF9VK8TRF6","is_track_user":"1","root_domain":"MyPluginOne-github.local","affiliate_link":[{"path":"https:\/\/wpbrigade.com\/?edd_action=add_to_cart&download_id=1835&edd_options%5Bprice_id%5D=4&_gl=1*bzfdf6*_ga*ODA1Mzc5NjgyLjE3MDM2ODA1MzM.*_ga_YCW7CRBRMF*MTcwNDM2NjA2Ny4xMi4wLjE3MDQzNjYxMTkuOC4wLjA.","label":"test"}],"download_extension":"zip|mp3*|mpe*g|pdf|docx*|pptx*|xlsx*|rar*","anchor_tracking":"on"};
</script>
```

I have used following way to add the comment but in it another script is generated:

```
$comment = "Your comment here";
wp_script_add_data('MyPluginOne-events-tracking', 'data', $comment);
```

but in this another script is created. How to fix this?

Comment: Read this. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/387674/wp-script-add-data-doesnt-seem-to-work - You probably want to use this https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_script/

Answer (score 1):

The analytify plugin has already enqueued the script, so your code is enqueueing it a second time.  Before your call to wp_enqueue_script, try adding:

```
wp_dequeue_script( 'analytify-events-tracking' );
```

which should work if the plugin has already enqueued the script when front_scripts runs.

Comment: but i require both js files

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood.  Could you please post the output you are getting so I can see what is undesirable about it?